# Windows 8 GridView maximum items (according to screen size)

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-8, microsoft-metro

I am creating an app for Windows 8 (not 8.1).

I would like to show some content on a screen in a way similar to the Windows Store app.

I am using a GridView currently but if needed another control can also be used.

What I require is as follows-

On a small screen, Windows store shows only 6 items in a category as follows-

[image: 6 items on small screen]

Whereas on a larger screen it shows 9 items as follows-

[image]

I would like to add a similar implementation but I don't know how.

Do I need to set only 6 items as source for the GridView when screen is small and 9 when screen is large?? Or can the GridView automatically show only as many items as can be visible in 3 columns and "n" number of rows??

Here is a sample code of my GridView- I am using a WrapGrid to limit the number of columns to 3

```
<Grid Name="MyGrid">
    <GridView Name="MyGridView">
        <GridView.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <WrapGrid Orientation="Horizontal" MaximumRowsOrColumns="3" />
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </GridView.ItemsPanel>
    <GridView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Grid>
                <Image Source="{Binding Icon}" Margin="10" Stretch="Uniform" Width="150" Height="150" />
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
    </GridView.ItemTemplate>
</GridView>
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can make an attached behavior and attach it on the ItemsWrapGrid. The behavior will listen for SizeChanged and automatically change the MaximumRowsOrColumns property based on the available space and size of items